# Dual check box selection vb / winform

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am after a little bit of help:

I have a datagridview control where I add another couple of columns (as check boxes) in order to select multiple rows.  When I select the first checkbox column I want the second to be selected automatically, but can then be de-selected if required.  And if the first checkbox is deselected, the 2nd is auto deselected too.

I have this working with the following code:

```
Private Sub dgvBikeAvailability_CellContentClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvBikeAvailability.CellContentClick

    Debug.Print("Row index = " + e.RowIndex.ToString + ". Column index = " + e.ColumnIndex.ToString + ". Column Name = ")
    'Debug.Print()
    'when a bike is selected, a helmet is automatically selected, but can be deselected if the customer requires
    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        dgvBikeAvailability.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value = Not dgvBikeAvailability.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value
        dgvBikeAvailability.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value = dgvBikeAvailability.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value
    End If

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, wen the datagridview is refreshed, the column indexes are incremented, and the column indexes for the 2 check box columns are now 2 and 3.

I would like to be able to refer to them by name.  They are declared in the sub that refreshes the datagridview:

```
colBikeSelectionCheckBox.HeaderText = "Select Bike"    
colBikeSelectionCheckBox.Name = "colSelectBike")
colHelmetCheckBox.Name = "colSelectHelmet"
dgvBikeAvailability.Columns.Add(colHelmetCheckBox)
```

but the System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs class does not allow me to select column name.

Any ideas and suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Edit:  More in depth code segment:

```
 Private Sub frmBikeHire_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    refreshGrid()
    getStaffMember()
End Sub

'loads and refreshes the dgv
Private Sub refreshGrid()
    Dim i As Integer

    'initially fill in the rental dates for current day
    txtDateFrom.Text = CStr(MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start)
    txtDateTo.Text = CStr(MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.End)

    'grab data from DB, set as dgv datasource
    startDate = CStr(MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start)
    endDate = CStr(MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.End)
    dtBikeAvailability = sqlFuncDB_getDataTable("SELECT * FROM tb_bikeDetail WHERE bikeid NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT bikeid FROM tb_bikemovements WHERE bikeMovementDate BETWEEN '" + func_convertDateSQLSERVER(startDate) + "' AND '" + func_convertDateSQLSERVER(endDate) + "') AND bikeid NOT IN (SELECT tb_bikemovements.bikeid FROM tb_bikemovements JOIN (SELECT bikeid, max(bikemovementdate) bmd FROM tb_bikemovements WHERE bikemovementdate < '" + func_convertDateSQLSERVER(startDate) + "' group by bikeid) lastmove ON lastmove.bikeid=tb_bikemovements.bikeid AND lastmove.bmd=tb_bikemovements.bikemovementdate WHERE bikeMovementType = '0')")
    dvBikeAvailability = New DataView(dtBikeAvailability)
    dgvBikeAvailability.DataSource = dvBikeAvailability

    'switch off all columns
    For i = 0 To dgvBikeAvailability.Columns.Count - 1
        dgvBikeAvailability.Columns(i).Visible = False
    Next

    'displays only relevant column(s)
    dgvBikeAvailability.Columns("bikeName").Visible = True
    dgvBikeAvailability.Columns("bikeName").HeaderText = "Bike Name"
    dgvBikeAvailability.Columns("bikeStyle").Visible = True
    dgvBikeAvailability.Columns("bikeStyle").HeaderText = "Bike Style"
    dgvBikeAvailability.Columns("bikeColour").Visible = True
    dgvBikeAvailability.Columns("bikeColour").HeaderText = "Bike Colour"

    'remove this line for program deployment
    dgvBikeAvailability.Columns("bikeID").Visible = True
    dgvBikeAvailability.Columns("bikeID").HeaderText = "Bike Number"

    'add new check box column for selecting the bike 
    Dim colBikeSelectionCheckBox As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
    colBikeSelectionCheckBox.DataPropertyName = "PropertyName"
    colBikeSelectionCheckBox.HeaderText = "Select Bike"
    colBikeSelectionCheckBox.Name = "colSelectBike"
    dgvBikeAvailability.Columns.Add(colBikeSelectionCheckBox)

    'add new column for selecting helmet - consider adding as default setting
    Dim colHelmetCheckBox As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
    colHelmetCheckBox.DataPropertyName = "PropertyName"
    colHelmetCheckBox.HeaderText = "Helmet?"
    colHelmetCheckBox.Name = "colSelectHelmet"
    dgvBikeAvailability.Columns.Add(colHelmetCheckBox)

    dgvBikeAvailability.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill

End Sub

Private Sub MonthCalendar1_DateChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DateRangeEventArgs) Handles MonthCalendar1.DateChanged
    refreshGrid()
End Sub

Private Sub dgvBikeAvailability_CellClick(sender As Object, e As     System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvBikeAvailability.CellClick
    Debug.Print("Row index = " + e.RowIndex.ToString + ". Column index = " + e.ColumnIndex.ToString + ". Column Name = " + dgvBikeAvailability.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("colSelectBike").OwningColumn.ToString)

    If dgvBikeAvailability.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "colSelectBike" Then
        dgvBikeAvailability.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("colSelectBike").Value = Not dgvBikeAvailability.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("colSelectBike").Value
        dgvBikeAvailability.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("colSelectHelmet").Value = dgvBikeAvailability.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("colSelectBike").Value
    End If

End Sub
```

I am unsure why that doesn't work.  Each time the calendar control is changed it refreshes the datagridview, which is increasing the column index.

Comment: You have a logical conflict in your design. Suppose you have check boxes A and B. When you select A, B is selected. You say that if you deselect B, A should be deselected. You also state that you can deselect B separately from A. I don't see how this is possible.

Comment: @Neolisk DazEvans states that if he deselects A, then B should be deselected. The logic appears workable to me.

Comment: @ Neolisk: If the user selects a bike (col 1) then helmet checkbox is auto selected, but then the user can elect to de-select the helmet.  If  the bike is deselected, the helmet should be deseleced as well.

Comment: @DazEvans: So it's one way binding from A to B, meaning whenever state of A is changed, state of B should be set equal to that. Changing B does not impact A. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the column index provided by the `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` class to retrieve the column and from that get the name to compare.

So something like:

```
If dgvBikeAvailability.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name == "colSelectBike" Then
    ' Your logic here
End If
```

For referencing the columns within your code to toggle the CheckBoxes, you can very happily use the names, and in fact do not need the index provided by the event args. The event args index appears to only be used to check that one of your desired columns was selected.

```
dgvBikeAvailability.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("colSelectBike").Value = Not dgvBikeAvailability.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("colSelectBike").Value
dgvBikeAvailability.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("colSelectHelmet").Value = dgvBikeAvailability.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("colSelectBike").Value
```

---

Although the code above *should* work it appears that something odd is happening with your grid. A quick solution is to instead of using the `.Add()` to use the `.Insert()` method of the DataGridView, which provided an index parameter, allowing you to directly control where your column goes.

Comment: One additional comment - you might want to look at how you are creating the check box columns. It is always better to reference columns by name for this very reason, but in principal it should be possible to refresh the grid and maintain the column indexes.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the response!  I want to be able to reference the columns by name, but the DataGridViewCellEventArgs class doesnt let me do it, it only lets me select col and row indexes.

Comment: @ David Hall I am still unsure how I can reference the column names in the if statement

Comment: The code I've provided addresses exactly that problem (or so I believe) - you can find which column you receive in the events by using the e.ColumnIndex property to look up the column from the datagrdview collection. In the if statement, you don't need to use the index from the cell events at all.

Comment: I'll edit in that code - I had thought that part self explanatory, but will show the idea. (Also, I'm prototyping this in C# and then typing the vb without testing, so there might be syntax errors, but the principle works)

Comment: No joy, I may be struggling to explain my problem to you, apologies.

I am displaying (debug.print) the row and col index for the selected check box, which is increasing by 2 each time the datagridview gets refreshed.  Is there an easy way to reset (or maintain) the column indexes on refresh?

Comment: Your problem seems to be that you cannot reference a column by name, yes? What is stopping you from using the code as shown? Why do you want to reference the column names in the if statement? Can you edit in the code that isn't working?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28898/discussion-between-david-hall-and-dazevans)